# Dspace metadata titles customizations

Tags: dspace

I am using dspace mirage2 and in the item view, the metadata fields are show as dc.contributor.author, dc.identifier.citation.

Which message.properties should I edit to change dc.contributor.author to Author and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible in Mirage 2 xmlui.